# How To Send Output To Terminal Window with Hive Script

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am familiar with storing output/results for a Hive Query to file, but what command do I use in the script to display the results of the HQL to the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my output:
[image]

There was no output, because I had yet to properly use the LOAD DATA INPATH command to my hdfs. After loading, I received output from the SELECT statement in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Normally Hive prints results to the stdout, if not redirected it displays on console. You do not need any special command for this.

If you want to display results on the console screen and at the same time store them in a file, use `tee` command:

```
hive -e "use mydb;  select * from test_t" | tee ./results.txt

OK
123     {"value(B)":"Bye"}
123     {"value(G)":"Jet"}
Time taken: 1.322 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

Check file contains results

```
cat ./results.txt
123     {"value(B)":"Bye"}
123     {"value(G)":"Jet"}
```

See here: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee